# How to carry value in query string By using button tag

Tags: php

```
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?corp_no=".$query2['corp_no']."'>OK</a></td>";   
echo "<td><a href='delete_form.php?corp_no=".$query2['corp_no']."'>Cancel</a></td>";
```

For above case, I wanna know how to write it with button tag?

Comment: why would you want to do that...? You could easily use CSS to make the anchor tag look like a button..!

Answer (score 0):

Php can be written directly with HTML

`<button type="button" formaction="delete_form.php?corp_no='<?php echo $query2['corp_no'] ;?>'">Cancel</button>`

The same method can also be used for OK button

Comment: when I write like that formaction doesn't work. it can't go to delete_form.php

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that a button 'does something' and a link 'goes somewhere' (actually changes the URI).

Currently there is **no** way to accomplish what you want via a button.

You can however pass information to a server within a `<form>` by using the `value` attribute on a `<button>`.

Perhaps an even better solution would be to style a `<a>` (link) to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

Either format your `<a>` tags with CSS to look like a button and call it a day, or you'll be using **Javascript** to accomplish this.

### `<button>` tag:

```
echo "<td><button onclick='window.location.href=\"edit.php?corp_no=".$query2['corp_no']."\";'>OK</button></td>";
```

Comment: @AheintMyet great glad to hear it.  If you are satisfied, please accept with the green checkmark on the left of the answer.  But if not, let me know how I can help.